# How to know if there is any account available to be selected using ADAL js

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, adal, adal.js

I have a situation where I need to redirect to a different url if the Azure account selection page doesn't list any account to be selected. I know after user select an account to login the callback gives some details of the user. But I want to know beforehand the user logs in i.e in the account selection page itself. Is there any way I can know there is no account is available to be selected in ADAL js methods?

Comment: Will the user be signing in using either their Azure AD or Personal Microsoft account?

Comment: @GauravMantri it could be either Azure AD or Personal MS account. my exact need is to upon landing on the account selection screen detect if user is an internal employee who will have AD app assignment or an external user who probably would see his personal MS account. so how I can extract that detail with the help of ADALjs.

Comment: It sounds like one of these situations where you want to know who the user might be before they authenticate. One way I've seen used is to collect the user email in your app, detect their type etc from that, and then forward them to AAD with login_hint=user@company.com. This way they won't need to enter their email twice. You cannot know if the user has accounts in SSO state.

Comment: You can try to use the method ```getCachedUser ```.

Comment: @JimXu does getCachedUser works before authentication?

Comment: @juunas exactly I want to know who the user might be before they authenticate. How do I know that

Comment: I gave you one option in my comment. As far as I know, ADAL has no way to tell you what accounts the user has.

Comment: Regarding the issue, please refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323